# ANR with blocked HeapTaskDaemon thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I get an ANR-error in my Android app. The trace shows only one thread in blocked state (all the others are in state waiting, sleeping, native,..), so it doesn't seem to be in deadlock. There are two threads which I start (directly) manually, so I roughly know in which part of my app the ANR occurs. Unfortunately, I can't make any sense of the trace of the blocked thread. Maybe anyone has an idea?

Blocked thread:

```
"HeapTaskDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 Blocked
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cfc8e0 self=0xab4b2bf0
  | sysTid=10048 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf4815930
  | state=S schedstat=( 113876044 26950467 98 ) utm=9 stm=2 core=5 HZ=100
  | stack=0xf4713000-0xf4715000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: pc 0000000000016908  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: pc 00000000000f604b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+82)
  native: pc 00000000001cddb1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor7GetTaskEPNS_6ThreadE+92)
  native: pc 00000000001ce2c5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+60)
  native: pc 000000000000036f  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_runHeapTasks__+74)
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks (Native method)
- waiting to lock an unknown object
  at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run (Daemons.java:355)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

This is the main thread:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x74da03b0 self=0xab36bea8
  | sysTid=10039 nice=13 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xf77a2b34
  | state=S schedstat=( 2234944203 2215960664 6968 ) utm=163 stm=60 core=6 HZ=100
  | stack=0xff794000-0xff796000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x07456fa0> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ (Thread.java:1220)
- locked <0x07456fa0> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:158)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:810)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:843)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1172)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock (ReentrantLock.java:181)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock (ReentrantLock.java:257)
  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow (SurfaceView.java:524)
  at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw (SurfaceView.java:179)
  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw (ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2082)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6050)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:860)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:672)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:608)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:846)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5441)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:738)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Nexus 7

Comment: Ddd you solved the problem, I am facing in Android 8.0 only is this the case for you also?

Comment: @ingsaurabh I am facing the same issue also only on Android 8.0 and 8.1, did you have any success?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Hae facing same issue in Moto device. Android 7.0.

Comment: how do you start your threads? can you post the code?

Comment: I have the exactly same problem. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Potentially related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225993/anr-internal-function-on-some-devices

Comment: Did you have any luck with this investigation? I'm trying to figure out the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Trying to put more information on this issue. So that it can help future user's.

As you said only one thread in **Blocked** state, it's clear that it is not a Deadlock. Threads marked as *blocked* will generally tell you what **mutex (lock)** they are trying to acquire and the **thread ID (tid)** of the thread holding that lock.

In this particular case

> - waiting to lock an unknown object

Above line tell neither what mutex(lock) it trying to acquire or thread ID holding that lock. (Maybe HeapTaskDaemon thread trying to lock some native object and in that attempt block due to some race condition). So just check with below information and identify the issue in your case and/or put forward an educated guess to prevent it.

On recent versions of Android, garbage collection(GC) generally runs on a background thread named **HeapTaskDaemon**. Note that significant amounts of allocation can mean more CPU resources spent on GC.

Systrace will show you if GC is running frequently, and the [Android Memory Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler) can show you where allocations are coming from. If you avoid allocations when you can, especially in tight loops, you shouldn't have a problem.

[check this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render#object_allocation_and_garbage_collection) for more information.

For more information on ANR and Deadlock's in Android [check this link](http://zenandroid.io/deadlocks-and-anrs/).

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `android:largeHeap="true"` in application Manifest?
        `